# Textmate not recognizing coffee script in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, textmate

For some reason my js.coffee file is not recognizing the coffee script?  At the bottom footer the format says plain text.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the coffeescript bundle found here:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle